# dynamic template field for datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have the following code to display images in datalist.

```
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
      string str="~/"+txt1.Text+"/";
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("str"));
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        foreach (FileInfo oItem in files)
        {
            if (oItem.Extension == ".jpg" || oItem.Extension == ".jpeg" || oItem.Extension == ".gif")
                list.Add(oItem);
            //Image ImageData= (Image)DataList1.FindControl("Image1");
            //ImageData.ImageUrl = dir.ToString()+"{0}";
        }
        DataList1.DataSource = list;
        DataList1.DataBind();

    }
```

in aspx:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="10" CellPadding="5">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Image Width="20" Height="20" ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/ajax _main/testpages/images/{0}") %>' runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/ajax _main/testpages/images/{0}") %>' runat="server"/>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle BorderColor="silver" BorderStyle="dotted" BorderWidth="3px" HorizontalAlign="Center"
VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
</asp:DataList>
```

I want to define this template in cs file, so that I can change navigate url according to the txt1.Text. can any one help me doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath(str));
```

note that i have removed `""` from str

And when you binding you can bind paths like below

```
var paths = dir.GetFiles()
    .Where(f => f.Extension == ".jpg" || f.Extension == ".jpeg" || f.Extension == ".gif")
    .Select(p => new { Name = MapPathReverse(p.FullName) })
    .ToList();
DataList1.DataSource = paths;
DataList1.DataBind();
```

To get the relative path from the physical path i have used below method

```
public static string MapPathReverse(string fullServerPath)
{
    return @"~\" + fullServerPath.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, String.Empty);
}
```

now you can change aspx binding to

```
ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Name") %>'
```

Comment: I get this errorSystem.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I was very much need of this. Thanks again